# Best way to conditionally include data table columns in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have many data tables which enable tight functions.  If I want more than one of the data table items to be conditionally compiled, however, it makes the table itself a mess.  Here is an example:

```
//#define USE_UNITS
//#define USE_RAW

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t alarm_num;
  uint8_t dec;
  boolean sign;
  PGM_P label;
  PGM_P label_suffix;
#ifdef  USE_UNITS
  PGM_P units;
#endif
#ifdef  USE_RAW
  boolean raw;
#endif
  boolean newline;
} TEST_TABLE_TYPE;

const TEST_TABLE_TYPE PROGMEM test_table[NUM_ALARMS] =
{
  {ALARM_VIN_UV_LVL, MEAS_VIN_VCAP_VOUT_DEC, false, label_vin_string, label_uv_string,
#ifdef  USE_UNITS
  units_volts_string,
#endif
#ifdef  USE_RAW
  false,
#endif
    false},
  {ALARM_VIN_OV_LVL, MEAS_VIN_VCAP_VOUT_DEC, false, label_vin_string, label_ov_string,
#ifdef  USE_UNITS
      units_volts_string,
#endif
#ifdef  USE_RAW
      false,
#endif
      false},
  {ALARM_IIN_OC_LVL, MEAS_IIN_ICHG_DEC, true, label_iin_string, label_oc_string,
#ifdef  USE_UNITS
    units_amps_string,
#endif
#ifdef  USE_RAW
    false,
#endif
    true},
  {ALARM_VOUT_UV_LVL, MEAS_VIN_VCAP_VOUT_DEC, false, label_vout_string, label_uv_string,
#ifdef  USE_UNITS
      units_volts_string,
#endif
#ifdef  USE_RAW
      false,
#endif
      false}
};
```

That is only 3 items too!  I might be better off just including 4 copies of the table selected by each possible combination of USE_UNITS and USE_RAW.

Is there a best way to have the data tables conditionally compile?

Comment: Have you considered having a rethink on the design. This will (is) a nightmare to test - unit or otherwised

Comment: suggest declare a struct that contains ALL the fields.  then in the code that accesses that struct, have different functions defined for each of the 4 conditions Then have a table of function pointers, one entry for each of the 4 conditions,  Then define  a selector those value is one of the 4 conditions, then access the appropriate function via that selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use macros to make this alternative less verbose:

```
//#define USE_UNITS
//#define USE_RAW

typedef struct {
    uint8_t alarm_num;
    uint8_t dec;
    boolean sign;
    PGM_P label;
    PGM_P label_suffix;
#ifdef  USE_UNITS
    PGM_P units;
#define X_UNITS(x) x,
#else
#define X_UNITS(x)
#endif
#ifdef  USE_RAW
    boolean raw;
#define X_RAW(x) x,
#else
#define X_RAW(x)
#endif
    boolean newline;
} TEST_TABLE_TYPE;

const TEST_TABLE_TYPE PROGMEM test_table[NUM_ALARMS] = {
  { ALARM_VIN_UV_LVL, MEAS_VIN_VCAP_VOUT_DEC, false, label_vin_string, 
    label_uv_string, X_UNITS(units_volts_string) X_RAW(false) false },
  { ALARM_VIN_OV_LVL, MEAS_VIN_VCAP_VOUT_DEC, false, label_vin_string,
    label_ov_string, X_UNITS(units_volts_string) X_RAW(false) false },
  { ALARM_IIN_OC_LVL, MEAS_IIN_ICHG_DEC, true, label_iin_string, 
    label_oc_string, X_UNITS(units_amps_string) X_RAW(false) true },
  { ALARM_VOUT_UV_LVL, MEAS_VIN_VCAP_VOUT_DEC, false, label_vout_string,
    label_uv_string, X_UNITS(units_volts_string) X_RAW(false) false }
};
```

But a better solution is to always include all fields. It does not consume much space and makes the code **much** more readable.

Comment: Thank you, that is much cleaner!  This is for embedded code that will be distributed, and some of the customers will be using small micros where they won't want to include certain things to save space.  Your solution works well for that.

Comment: @BigBobby: be careful with the commas: there is no comma after the `X_UNITS(x)` macro.  You can also generalize this method to instantiate multiple fields at a time if they are all optional based on the same condition, just change the macro to take multiple arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Write a program (not necessarily in C) to output C code with your tables.

Include the output of that program into your original program.

```
#include "output_of_intermediary_program.h" // or maybe .c
```

You can integrate this method into makefiles and other build tools.

Comment: This would work if this was only for my personal use, but I'm writing this as code that will be distributed and used in a variety of embedded systems.  It is simpler for me to distribute code configurable through #defines than code with an automatically generated file.